# XCode: Stack view and constraints

Tags: xcode, uistackview

Why would I need contraints on elements that live inside my stack view? Is not the idea of the Stack View to stack elements automatically thus making the need of explicit measures to be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Said. `Stackview` get its height and width from `content size`.
Sometime we cannot say exactly how much `content size` a `ui element` has.

For example if we have an `imageview` inside `stackview` and we assign `image` at runtime. The `stackview` will grow with the `imageview`. The question is how much. Well it depends on the size of image. So there we can feel undesired results. So we fix `stackview` size using predefined `constraints`.

Also, `Stackview` need `constraints` for position. Where to position `stackview` inside view of `viewcontroller`. So we need `constraints` for positioning our `stackview`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for horizontal rules but How about height for vertical stack views? XCode is nagging me that I need a height but I really don't know how long it will be or I don't really care. I can wrap the content on a Scroll View but the height of the Stack View should be ignored.

Comment: As @Irfan say `Stackview get its height and width from content size.` this sentence is the key.